# Problem with outputting object properties to html and saving object properties to file

Tags: php, html

People, hello everyone, I can't understand myself. Created a Car class, it has properties: model, color, etc.

There are two methods, one method displays these fields on the page, the second should write them to a file. To call these methods, I send two post requests from index to other pages, where I create new Car objects, assign values ​​to the object's fields, then try to call its methods. But both of these methods do not work for me; where the output should be, only empty lines are displayed
My Class Car

```
class Car
{
    public $model_car;
    public $color_car;
    public $horserpower_car;
    public $production_year_car;
    public function show()
    {
        echo <<<HTML
            <h1>Model</h1>
            <h3><?= $this->model_car?></h3>
            <h1>Color</h1>
            <h3><?= $this->color_car?></h3>
            <h1>Power</h1>
            <h3><?= $this->horserpower_car?></h3>
            <h1>Production_year</h1>
            <h3><?= $this->production_year_car?></h3>
        HTML;
    }
    public function save()
    {
        $filename = "reports/".$this->model_car."_".$this->production_year_car."txt";
        $content = "Model - ".$this->model_car."\n, Production year - " . $this->$this->production_year_car.
        "\n, Power - " . $this->horserpower_car."\n, Production year - " . $this->production_year_car;
        if(!file_put_contents($filename,$content))
        {
            echo "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Complete";
        }
    }
}
```

the method that should save the object, swears that I cannot convert this object to a string. It feels like my object's fields are empty.
My show.php

```
<?php
require "Car.php";
$car = new Car();
$car->model_car = "Toyota";
$car->color_car = "LightGreen";
$car->horserpower_car = 110;
$car->production_year_car = 2011;
$car->show();
```

My save.php

```
<?php
require "Car.php";
$car = new Car();
$car->model_car = "Toyota";
$car->color_car = "LightGreen";
$car->horserpower_car = 110;
$car->production_year_car = 2011;
$car->save();
```

My index.php

```
<body>


<form action="show.php" method="post">
    <h1>Show</h1>
    <button type="submit">Show</button>
</form>
<form action="save_file.php" method="post">
    <h1>Save</h1>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message please? And which line throws it? Paraphrasing, abbreviating or otherwise altering the error messages when you report them to us only hinders our ability to diagnose the problem. Always be clear, specific, accurate and unambiguous in your descriptions please.

Comment: When i try save file
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class Car could not be converted to string in

Comment: And which line of code exactly does that report mention?

Comment: Your HEREDOC usage is wrong. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc _“Warning
It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except a semicolon (;). That means especially that **the identifier may not be indented**, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.”_

Comment: The line `$content = "Model - ".$this->model_car."\n, Production year - " . $this->$this->production_year_car.` has two `$this->$this->`...

Comment: @CBroe That's been changed in recent versions of PHP (from version 7 I believe). Indentation is now allowed for the closing heredoc-identifier

Comment: I solved the first error with the output, I needed to replace <? =?> with {...}. But I still cannot write the fields of an object to a file.

Comment: "cannot" means what exactly? That isn't an error message or a problem description. Please update the question with  your most recent code, and explain what is going wrong currently - whether that's an error message or some other unexpected result. We can't help you unless you are specific about the issue.